# Semantic UI multisite

Tags: semantic-ui

Hello Stack community !

I use Semantic UI and I would like to know if it's possible to manage multiple themes (several themes in dist folder) for multiple sites in a single compilation (via gulp build) ? For my front and my backoffice ?

> For example :

```
src/themes/site-1/
src/themes/site-2/
```

> gulp compilation will generate :

```
/dist/site-1/semantic.css
/dist/site-2/semantic.css
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom css for your sites (site1.css etc.) Your custom css classes are overwrites to Semantic UI.

For Site1 ;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/semantic.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/site1.css" />
```

For Site2 ;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/semantic.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/site2.css" />
```

i hope this would help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way this obliges me to include every default rules of Semantic UI (too fat for me ;) ).

I asked the author by today, there is no simple way to do what I want to do... maybe in the future (I hope).

Finally I have two full Semantic UI folder (1 for each). I need to compile twice but this work fine.