# Multi-tenancy and Semantic UI

Tags: gulp, themes, multi-tenant, semantic-ui, multisite

I'm looking for a way to use multiple SUI themes within my Laravel application, one theme for each tenant (website). I have Semantic UI (`semantic-ui-less` repo) installed as a node_module.

Somehow I need to have multiple `theme.config` files in order to point to different `site` folders to override the default theme. Again, one for each tenant. I could then build a theme for a specific tenant using Gulp. Overriding the `theme.config` file each gulp build is also an option, but I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Another options I could think of is to have multiple composer.json files for each tenant. But I think this is overkill for theming only and it could cause collision problems.

There is nothing to find on the internet, except for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785485/semantic-ui-multisite) unanswered question. I hope someone could help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a pretty cool solution which replaces the `siteFolder` variable within theme.config to point to the right directory. After that I can compile the less files.

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var Elixir  = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var rename  = require('gulp-rename');
var util    = require('gulp-util');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Tenants
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Build Semantic UI individually for each tenant.
 |
 */
if (typeof util.env.tenant === 'string') {

    var tenant = util.env.tenant;
    var tenantPath = 'storage/tenants/' + tenant + '/assets';
    var semanticPath = 'node_modules/semantic-ui-less/';

    Elixir.extend('theme', function(tenant) {

        new Elixir.Task('theme', function() {
            /**
             * Perform some magic by pointing the @siteFolder variable
             * to the current tenant's theme directory in order for each
             * tenant to have it's own unique Semantic UI theme.
             */
            return gulp.src([semanticPath + 'theme.config.example'])
                .pipe(replace("'site'", "'../../" + tenantPath + "/theme'"))
                .pipe(rename('theme.config'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(semanticPath));
        });

    });

    Elixir(function(mix) {
        mix
            .theme(tenant)
            .less(semanticPath + '/semantic.less', tenantPath + '/css/semantic.min.css')
            .scriptsIn(semanticPath . '/definitions', tenantPath + '/js/semantic.min.js')
            .copy(semanticPath + '/themes/default/assets', tenantPath + '/css/themes/default');
    });

}
```

**Usage**
`gulp --tenant {name}`